# SPD2010 Workflow - Calculating Costs after importing amounts

Tags: designer-workflow, export, updatelistitems

I'm running 2 database that share information. Main Dbase is "Requests" and runs my workflow.  The second Dbase is "Funding".  I need to export the "Estimated Cost" from the Request Dbase and ADD it to the "Estimated Costs" in my Funding Dbase for a running total.  There are 5 different areas with 3 Request Types each.  So I need something like

- If List item [Area] = X
- and List item [Request Type] = Y
- THEN Export List item [Export Cost] to "Funding"

And this is where I'm stuck.  How do I get the cost to go to the right Area/Request Type record? I also need to ADD it to what's there and not just replace it.

Answer (score 1):

It should look something like.

Start when new items added

Set workflow variable X equal to (get data from funding DBase where area = item.area and type = item.type)

Do calculation workflow variable X plus item.amount write to variable Y

Set field in other list to Y (where area = item.area and type = item.type)

**You may need to have a calculated field on both lists that does a combination of Area/Type so that you can single field match it in the workflow.**